# Jetty plugin only maven dependency

Tags: maven, jetty

I'm developing CXF web services with JDK 7 + Eclipse Juno + Maven 3 and deploying on a WebSphere 7 Application Server.

I've spent hours to fiund the right configuration of dependencies (a complex mix of runtime, system, compile and provided scopes) that the WAS accepts without conflicts, but with this configuration my jetty plug in does not work anymore.

How can I specify a classpath specific only for the Jetty plugin (hopefully a maven configuration)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the only way to make the jetty plugin working properly regarding all those dependency issues is to specify all dependencies that are `<provided>` in your webapp as direct dependencies of the jetty plugin (and unfortunately, this brings kind of redundancy):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.0.v20130308</version>
    ...
   <dependencies>
     <!-- put here all your dependencies with scope provided in your webapp -->
     <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>3.0</version>
     </dependency>
     ...
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```